# Raster clip in ArcMap changing the pixel size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, clip

I have a masked raster layer (ESRI grid format) of a large area that I'm trying to clip in ArcMap 10.3. Cell size is key for further analysis, thus I need to maintain the cell size of the clipped layer to 30 x 30 (the original masked layer is 30 x 30). However, when I clip the layer, the cell size for both X and Y reduces to 29.99806155. Unfortunately, this minute change does impact my analysis, and I don't know (a) why this is occurring, and (b) how to prevent it. I've tried adjusting the processing extent and cell size to prevent this change, but to no avail. Any advice?

Comment: does your clip extent boundaries line up with the raster cells?

Comment: @Midavalo Yes, it is. I snap to raster'd the layer to the input raster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find one solution to my problem: I used the Int tool (Spatial Analyst). After I clipped my raster, I selected Int, changed the cell size to 30 under the Environment > Raster Analysis > Cell Size, saved a new output, and ran the tool. My cell sizes went back to 30x30, and there are no distortion issues when I compared the new output to my original masked raster. Granted, this doesn't answer how to prevent the problem in the future, so I'll keep trying.